# Grails How to set resultTransformer on DetachedCriteria?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

In Grails 3.1 I have this code:

```
def criteria = new DetachedCriteria(SampleObject).build {}
criteria.projections {
    property('id')
}
criteria.list()
```

That returns a list of ids (Long). But I want a list of SampleObject with the id.

The problem is I dont find the method "setResultTransformer" on DetachedCriteria to do something like:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

There is a way to transform the result in a bean using DetachedCriteria?